# Unable to find any Xcode installations that supports iOS Simulator 13.2.2

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, titanium

I am getting this error when using titanium and trying to run my app on iOS simulator . I could do it before. My SDK version is 7.5.0.GA. How can I make it fine?
I use the command below to build my app:
`ti build -p ios -T simulator`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62654115/error-unable-to-find-any-xcode-installations-that-supports-ios-simulator-13-2-2/62654839#62654839 i also had similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

7.5.0.GA is from 2018. I strongly recommend updating the SDK to the latest (currently 9.0.3.GA) to make your app work again with the latest simulators and be able to push it to the app store. Check:
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Titanium+Compatibility+Matrix#TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-iOS
for a compatibility chart

Comment: we updated and it did not help. the problem does not seem to be update issue

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I push th e command to use specific simulator? I read that I can do it with adding "-C <name of the simulator>"to the command but I am not sure how to use it. How should I write the name of the simulator ?

Comment: Just use `appc ti build -p ios -C ?` (broken command) and it will display a CLI menu where you can select the simulator by number and you can see the ids